# Does the principle of action/reaction apply to light and its emitter?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, visible-light, photons, momentum, conservation-laws

If light has momentum, I guess conservation of momentum should apply? Does it mean that a LED emitting a photon in some direction receives a "push" in the opposite direction?

Comment: Yes.... many answers on this site.  Use the search for "photon momentum".

Comment: photons don't just have momentum, they have the maximum momentum possible, at fixed energy.